# Creating a button on a View from a second View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have this app I'm working on, which on a second view asks (textfield) the name for a button to be created on first view. After specifying the name and pressing OK button, the first view pops up (as demanded) but there's no new button, although created indeed. Can I use the following code in a second view method, to "refresh" the first view before presenting itself. What's wrong with this code? Any other approach? Thank you.

```
-(void)initWithView:(View1Controller *)aSuperview
{
    theSuperview = aSuperview;
}

- (IBAction)itemNameButton
{
    ...
    CGRect rectang;
    rectang = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);// just in case
    [theSuperview.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:rectang];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Post a code where you actually create your button and add it to the view. The code you've posted looks irrelevant to the problem you describe

Comment: Vladimir, I've posted a more detailed code.

Comment: Please don't mix views and view controllers. They are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You should adhere to the Model-View-Controller paradigm.  Views creating buttons in other views is a bad thing in general.  Instead, there should be a controller (probably a UIViewController subclass) that handles receiving the input from view 2 when the user clicks OK (via an action and a outlet to the textfield) and then tells view 1 (a custom view subclass) what to do using a defined set of methods (something like -addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle).  The process of adding the button itself should be fairly straight forward, something like:

```
- (void)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle {
    UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // whatever type you want

    newButton.titleLabel.text = buttonTitle;

    [self addSubview:newButton];
    newButton.center = self.center; // set your position here
}
```

Comment: Ben, please checkout my post.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller's responsibility is to control a given view. Its responsibility is *not* to communicate with other controllers in order to ask them to change their views, so doing this sort of thing is usually an indication of bad design.

You should have a method in your superview's controller which adds the button to its view, and then use delegation in order to be notified by your subview when it's necessary to add the button.

For a nice and simple introduction to delegates and protocols, I found [this blog post](http://johnnytrops.com/blog/wp/?p=332) to be one of the best out there.